# how to return max value of each column from a dataframe using for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, crosstab

I have a dataframe that i perform a crosstab function and return a dataframe object where i want to return the **max()** value of each column but when i try to iterate over the dataframe using for loop the system crash and display the below error:

```
 for m in range(len(maxvalue)):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

the type of  maxvalue is **numpy.int64**

## code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Dataframe({'event_type': ['watch movie ', 'stay at home', 'swimming','camping','meeting'], 
               'year_month': ['2020-08', '2020-05', '2020-02','2020-06','2020-01'],
                'event_mohafaza':['loc1','loc3','loc2','loc5','loc4'],
                 ' number_person ':[24,39,20,10,33],})

    grouped_df=pd.crosstab(df['year_month'], df[event_type])
    print(type(grouped_df))
                        
    for x in grouped_df.columns:                
          mx = []
          maxvalue =grouped_df[x].max()
          str(maxvalue)
          print(type(maxvalue)) 
          print(maxvalue) 
    
          for m in range(len(maxvalue)):
                mx.append(m)
          print(mx)
```

the expected result is :
1
509
92
332
14

**where each value is the max value in its column**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: This line is causing the problem and is completely unnecessary `for m in range(len(maxvalue)):`. You are getting an integer as per  the printed message, integers have no `len`. Remove the line and all shall be well. Jus leave `mx.append(maxvalue)`

Comment: @pavel i tried your answer it returns  each value in a list so i have now 5 lists  what i want is to combine all these list into one list.